# Retrofit with RxJava can't handle response with code 422

Tags: android, retrofit, rx-java

I encountered a weird bug with retrofit and can't find the cause. 
I have a POST call which can get an 422 error code as response. I'm logging HTTP communication with HttpLogger and these are my request and response logs.

```
--> POST http://'some url':8000/api/v1/lectures/1/reviews http/1.1
 D/OkHttp: Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
 D/OkHttp: Content-Length: 76
 D/OkHttp: Authorization: Bearer 'token'
 D/OkHttp: {"stars":12}
 D/OkHttp: --> END POST (76-byte body)
```

and while I expect response with 422 error code this is the response I get

```
<-- 200 OK http://'some url':8000/ (709ms)
 D/OkHttp: Date: Tue, 03 Jan 2017 14:09:40 +0000
 D/OkHttp: Connection: close
 D/OkHttp: X-Powered-By: PHP/7.1.0
 D/OkHttp: Cache-Control: no-cache
 D/OkHttp: Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
 D/OkHttp: Date: Tue, 03 Jan 2017 14:09:40 GMT
 D/OkHttp: <!DOCTYPE html>
     /* whole landing page html */
 D/OkHttp: </html>
 D/OkHttp: <-- END HTTP (49849-byte body)
```

Do anyone has any idea why is this happening ? Or is there any special way to handle 422 error code in Retrofit ? I'll post any part of my code if you need.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure that the http code is 422? It seams that the end point return 200. You should use a tool like Postman to confirm that the http code is 422

Comment: Well the problem is that the endoint in request and endpoint in response isn't the same. In response it's the root url of my API calls, which makes no sense to me ...

Comment: It looks odd indeed. But you should first consume the endpoint with a proper tool and make sure that the Retrofit is the problem.

Take a look at postman, it is the one I use: https://www.getpostman.com/

Comment: Thanks for advice, turns out the problem might indeed be on server side, Postman shows the same result